# Import MS Word form fields into MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-word

I have created an application form using MS Word and a whole bunch of form fields, and I have an Access db that can import all the data I need from this Word doc, thanks to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155434%28office.10%29.aspx

Now everything works just fine (I even managed to get it to import into multiple tables!), but the problem with the above is that I have to manually enter the name of each file one at a time... which is fine if it's just a case of importing the application form as it comes in... but I have quite a lot sitting in a folder that needs entered into the database.

Then I found this:

[How to show "Open File" Dialog in Access 2007 VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091484/how-to-show-open-file-dialog-in-access-2007-vba)

I've tried to tweak and merge the two to make it work... but as you can guess, to no avail... (it doesn't help when I'm very much an Access novice!)

What I am looking to do is to be able to import a bunch of Word docs / form fields into MS Access by using the Open / Select file dialogue box... what I've got works, but I'd like to make it easier to work with!

Thanks everyone
Jake

##### Codes I been using

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdFileDialog_Click()

' This requires a reference to the Microsoft Office 11.0 Object Library.

Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim varFile As Variant

Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
' Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
' Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strDocName As String
Dim blnQuitWord As Boolean

' Clear the list box contents.
' Me.FileList.RowSource = ""

' Set up the File dialog box.
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fDialog
' Allow the user to make multiple selections in the dialog box.
.AllowMultiSelect = True

' Set the title of the dialog box.
.Title = "Select One or More Files"

' Clear out the current filters, and then add your own.
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Microsoft Word", "*.DOC"
.Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
' False, the user clicked Cancel.
If .Show = True Then
' Loop through each file that is selected and then add it to the list box.
For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
' Me.FileList.AddItem varFile

Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open(varFile)

' cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
'     "Data Source=M:\Medical\GPAppraisal\Contacts & Databases\" & _
'     "AppForm.mdb;"
' rst.Open "tbl_Applicants", cnn, _
'     adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

' With rst
.addnew
!Title = doc.FormFields("wTitle").Result
!FirstName = doc.FormFields("wFirstName").Result
!LastName = doc.FormFields("wLastName").Result
!Address1 = doc.FormFields("wAddress1").Result
!Address2 = doc.FormFields("wAddress2").Result
!Address3 = doc.FormFields("wAddress3").Result
!City = doc.FormFields("wCity").Result
!PostCode = doc.FormFields("wPostCode").Result
!Email = doc.FormFields("wEmail").Result
!Phone1 = doc.FormFields("wPhone1").Result
!Phone2 = doc.FormFields("wPhone2").Result
!LM = doc.FormFields("wLM").Result
!LMAddress1 = doc.FormFields("wLMAddress1").Result
!LMAddress2 = doc.FormFields("wLMAddress2").Result
!LMAddress3 = doc.FormFields("wLMAddress3").Result
!LMCity = doc.FormFields("wLMCity").Result
!LMPostCode = doc.FormFields("wLMPostCode").Result
!LMEmail = doc.FormFields("wLMEmail").Result
!LMPhone = doc.FormFields("wLMPhone").Result
!LMOK = doc.FormFields("wLMOK").Result
!Probity = doc.FormFields("wProbity").Result
!Practising = doc.FormFields("wPractising").Result
!Signature = doc.FormFields("wSignature").Result
!AppDate = doc.FormFields("wAppDate").Result
!e2011012028 = doc.FormFields("w2011012028").Result
!e2011021725 = doc.FormFields("w2011021725").Result
!e2011030311 = doc.FormFields("w2011030311").Result
!e2011031625 = doc.FormFields("w2011031625").Result
!e20110203 = doc.FormFields("w20110203").Result
!e20110211 = doc.FormFields("w20110211").Result
!e20110322 = doc.FormFields("w20110322").Result
!e20110330 = doc.FormFields("w20110330").Result
.Update
.Close
End With
doc.Close
If blnQuitWord Then appWord.Quit
cnn.Close
MsgBox "Application Imported!"

Cleanup:
' Set rst = Nothing
' Set cnn = Nothing
Set doc = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing

Next
Else
   MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
End If
End With
End Sub
```

#

I've tried to mess with me.tables and me!forms and .add etc etc - obviously I'm a complete novice here!!!

What I want is to be able to import data from form fields in a Word Doc into a MS Access table (which I have managed to do with the first URL in my original post above); by means of selecting the Word doc from the Open/Select dialogue box, instead of manually entering the names of each Word doc.

My apologies if it sounds obvious or simple - Access is not my strong point by any means!

Comment: Can you give us a step-by-step of what you're doing? Also, how comfortable are you with VB & VBA? I ask because a solution will probably require a modest amount of it.

Comment: So your question is about the dialog setting right? What would you like to be different there?

Comment: Thanks for all your prompt responses!

Comment: Ooops... hit the Enter button too quick... anyway, yes thanks for the prompt responses, here's the codes I been playing with:

Answer (score 1):

Before I begin I didn't understand why you have so many uncommented lines (lines beginnig mit ' ) in you code example. I assume that most of those lines would normally not bei uncommented and be part of the working code. Or are there artifacts of the Stack Overflow Editor?

I see a few problems, that might to guide you to a solution.

1) When you use

```
With fDialog
```

you let this 'open' until the end of the code (even using a second With in between). I would recommend to set you corresponding 'End With' right after you no longer require it. Remeber (or take note): The

```
With fDialog
   [... something]
   ' Set the title of the dialog box.
   .Title = "Select One or More Files"
```

is really just a shorthand for

```
fDialog.Title
```

(i.e. a "naked" . means, that it has to be appendend to the object in the With) so you could do away with the "With" entirely. IN you example I would set the "End With" right before

```
If .Show = True Then
```

and then use

```
If fDialog.Show = True Then
```

2) I would set

```
Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
```

*outside* your For Each loop (don't forget to take Set appWord = Nothing outside the loop as well). Remember that with GetObject you need an runnig Word-instance, otherwise you might want to use

```
Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

or to have it both ways, try to get a Word-object, and if it is not available (i.e. Err.Number = 429) create a new one.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number = 429 Then
    Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

3) When working or at least while developping using automation I would always set

```
objword.Visible = True
```

so you see error messages or other problems right within Word.

HTH for the next steps (in case you have this problem anymore)
Andreas