# Explore for files in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that a user uses to upload a CSV file.  Right now the user has to type the full file path of the file into a text box.  How can I get a browse for file popup to allow the user to navigate to the file instead of having to type the whole path?  Is the functionality already present and I just don't know how to use it yet?

Comment: look up File Picker dialog box

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813598/using-the-browse-for-file-dialog-in-access-vba

Comment: Thanks for the response I will take a look at both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show "Open File" Dialog in Access 2007 VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091484/how-to-show-open-file-dialog-in-access-2007-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create your own class with API calls. [Here you have the code](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Utilities/GUI_Resource_Tracer/VB6_GuiResTracer_zip_GCommonDialog_cls.asp). Or you can add a reference to Microsoft Office xx Object Library and use the FileDialog class. 
[Here you have an example of usage.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091484/how-to-show-open-file-dialog-in-access-2007-vba)

I prefer the first method, because you are not attached to an external library.