# How do you reference a closed Excel Workbook from a variable string?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make an Excel template for my co-worker which would allow them to easily process data which they download from their database. It needs to be as simple as possible on their end since many are not tech savvy.

My Idea was something like having a cell where they can just type the name of the file and all then everything would automatic load.

I was able to do this but it will only work if the file being referenced is already open. I believe this is because I am using VBA. It will take data from a closed workbook if I don't use VBA, but then I need to write the full refence code, and can't piece it together from other cells.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | File Name |
| 2 | Path |
| 3 | Ref Code |
| 4 | Data |

Do you know of any function which would work here?

Comment: If you are even a little bit comfortable in VBA, consider using the File Open dialog code here to give the users a familiar file-selecting experience: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201297/open-windows-level-fileopen-dialog-via-vba