# MS Access - How to open attachment window in form by button

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

How can I create a button in form to open attachment window by clicking on it using macros or vba?
[image: attachment window]

Answer (score 1):

Saving objects in database tables uses up Access 2GB size limit. Attachment field is a multi-value type and can be frustrating to manage. Most experienced developers leave files in external folder location. Review [Add/view attachments using MS Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237180/add-view-attachments-using-ms-access-vba) and [Access Attachment Dialog Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994118/access-attachment-dialog-window).

However, following code worked for me.

```
Me.attachmentcontrolname.SetFocus
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdManageAttachments
```