# Browse for file and move to folder

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I've searched around and found a few answers but none seem to fulfill exactly what I'm trying to do.

I want to creat a button that will open a window and allow the user to select a file from windows explorer and the move that file to a folder using information from the form.

So when the button is clicked, the user will browse to the file and select it, then press ok. After clicking "ok", the file is then moved to a fold name "Text57", "Text59" and rename the file to MYFILE.PDF

Comment: This might get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091484/how-to-show-open-file-dialog-in-access-2007-vba

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for.  I was able to find what I needed and alter it to fit my needs, I'll post it when I get back to my work computer.