# How to call GetOpenFileName?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have code in an Access database.

```vb
Private Sub Text0_Click()
    Dim s As String

    s = MyGetOpenFileName

    Me.Text0.Value = s
End Sub
```

In Windows 7 Office 2010 when I click the text box the windows open.

In Windows 10 Office 2013 nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

Dim OpenFile As Workbook

```
fPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel files, *.xl; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb; *.xlam; *.xltx; *.xls; *.xlt ", Title:="You can type the title for Your window here")

If fPath = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set OpenedFile = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=fPath, UpdateLinks:=0, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
```

I show the window with filter to excel files and then check if file is seleted if true then I open file.

Comment: sorry this code give me a compiler error (user - defined type not defined)

Comment: Ok, I've seen that Your question is taged with Excel, so my code was for excel vba. I think that for access database might be helpful this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091484/how-to-show-open-file-dialog-in-access-2007-vba